# Display datagrid when a Button is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid which is already binded to a DB. 
how to display data on the datagrid when a button is clicked ?

here is what I have tried...

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = null;
        DataSet ds = null;
        try
        {
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Major", @"Data Source=Student;Initial Catalog=StudDB;Integrated Security=true;Persist Security Info=True;");
            da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 100000;
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post some code that you have tried so far...

Comment: Pls check the changes in my question

Comment: Is your dataGrid1 hidden or somewhat?

Comment: you mean - AutoGenerateColumns="True" ? @Eugene

Comment: I mean if your dataGrid1.Visibillity = Visibillity.Hidden (or Collapsed) see @Florian answer. So, where is problem: you want to show dataGrid or you don't see data into it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution. Thanks to others who hav replied !

```
    SqlConnection con;
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ComputerName;Initial Catalog=YourDBName;Persist Security Info=True;");
            con.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = null;
        DataSet ds = null;
        try
        {
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from YourTableName",con);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 100000;
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

and in Xaml set the Itemsource and AutoGenerateColumns

```
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourTableName}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Grid.Column="1" Height="423" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,24,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="591" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a boolean property, which value changes after the button click.
Now you bind this property to the Visibility-property of your DataGrid. Use the BooleanToVisibilityConverter to convert the value.

Dont forget to notify your View when the boolean property changes (NotifyPropertyChanged-Event).